# "C# base class virtual function" - "override in Managed C++ ref class"

Tags: c#, c++, virtual, overriding, managed

I have a .NET_4 Managed C++ ref class that I derive from a .NET_4 base class written in C#.

C# base class:

```
namespace Core
{
  public class ResourceManager
  {
    public class _Resource
    {
      public virtual void Delete() {}
    }
  }
}
```

Managed C++ class:

```
namespace Input.DI
{
  public ref class Mouse : ResourceManager::_Resource
  {
    public:
    virtual void Delete() {}
  };
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

> 'Input::DI::Mouse::Delete' : matches base ref class method 'Core::ResourceManager::_Resource::Delete', but is not marked 'new' or 'override'; 'new' (and 'virtual') is assumed

What is the correct managed C++ syntax to override a `virtual` function from a C# class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You put `override` [after the function signature](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41w3sh1c.aspx).

```
//MANAGED C++ CLASS
namspace Input.DI
{
  public ref class Mouse : ResourceManager::_Resource
  {
    public:
    virtual void Delete() override {}
  };
}
```

Comment: Note that you have a typo (admittedly copied from OP) with _namspace_. That should read `namespace`. I don't wish to suggest an edit (I'm under 2k) as there's nothing more I could improve with your answer